# Vertically align two pieces of text with different font-sizes using CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, alignment

At the top of my page I want to have the title of the page aligned to the left of the screen with a short nav menu aligned to the right of the screen. I can achieve this using float but the two elements have different baslines i.e. the baseline of the text appears different. Is there any way to get this to work using css? I have a sample of what I'm trying to do up on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nBPCG/63/

Comment: CSS doesn't allow the // single line comment. It's messing up your header div{} style.

Comment: You also have the problem of the header div {...} style being applied to the clear div, causing it not to work right.  I would add an id to the title div so you can target just that div.

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing out those errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use display:inline-block in your h1

or see the Fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/nBPCG/101/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but using this method the nav menu is aligned with the center of the title whereas I want it aligned with the bottom

Answer (score 0):

First I'd suggest using a `ul` to wrap the links rather than an `h3`, that structure doesn't make sense. Then I'd just add some padding to the `ul`. Here's a cleaned up example of the markup:

```
<article >
<header>
    <h1>This is Title</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</header>
</article>
```

And the styles:

```
body {
    font-family:"Verdana", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight:400;
}

h1 {
    font-family:"Century Gothic", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight:400;
    float: left;
    margin-left:10px;
}

header nav {
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2em 0 0 0;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight:400;
}

nav a {
    padding: 0 1em;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

nav li:last-child a {
    padding-right: 0;
    border-right: none;
}

.clr {clear:both;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nBPCG/98/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but using this method the nav menu is aligned with the center of the title whereas I want it aligned with the bottom. I wrapped the links in h3 because they use that styling, adding in the list item seems rather redundant